# Can a homeowner replace this radiant floor heating plumbing part?

Tags: plumbing, hvac, water-circulating-heating

My investigations of my non-working hydronic floor heating system led me to the conclusion that the part in the picture is malfunctioning. Can someone let me know what that part actually is and whether a homeowner with minimal plumbing skills can replace it. There are shutoff valves right above and right below the part.

[image]

I'm now removed the strainer plug, but unsure what if anything can be checked there. Here's the picture:

[image]

Comment: Please include pictures (and the text) of any writing or markings on this piece. That would help confirm or deny Armand's answer and is always helpful when asking about an unknown (to you) part.

Comment: @FreeMan The only marking is at the top on the side that says INLET. An HVAC company came out and told me that it's an "autofeeder" and that they can replace it for $980 but wouldn't give me any more details.

Comment: Why do you think this pressure regulator is causing problems?

Comment: Do you feel comfortable in cleaning out the strainer yourself? If that doesn't help, I would contact a plumber, not an HVAC company. Email them the 3 photos in your link and see what they suggest.

Comment: @Armand The HVAC company that quoted $980 diagnosed it.

Comment: @Armand  I added the picture of what I see after I remove the strainer plug. Not seeing anything there.

Comment: The mesh on the strainer would be obviously clogged if that were the issue; sounds like it's something more complicated. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a pressure-reduction valve, with water entering from the top and continuing out the bottom. If similar to the one in the diagram below, the fitting on the side above the bell would be a strainer you can remove to clean. That's certainly the first thing to try doing.

The bell part is removable for other service, and repair parts kits are available. If you can find a manufacturer's name and model number on it, that would be a big help. With that, you may be able to find an installation/repair manual online with more details; otherwise, talk to a knowledgeable plumbing supply house.

In your specific case, the valve seems to be connected as follows from the top down: 1) threaded connection to upstream pipe (white teflon tape and blue pipe sealant on threads), 2) union connection (part of valve unit) with big hex nut, 3) threaded connection to downstream pipe (again white teflon tape and blue pipe sealant on threads).

The removal process would entail shutting off the upstream and downstream shutoffs, undoing the union connection, then unscrewing the upper and lower threaded sections. Reinstallation would be the reverse and would also likely involve flushing any trapped air and/or grit as well as setting the pressure to the desired value for your system.

The parts price for a similar valve in late 2022 seems to be a few hundred dollars on up; installation labor and adjustment would obviously add to the total price. In addition to asking for a total estimate, it would be useful to have a rough parts and labor breakdown. I would think that once the plumber/installer is on-site, it would take only an hour of labor to replace the valve.

[image]

Here are the maintenance instructions for the pictured valve:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Doesn't seem to have any markings: https://photos.app.goo.gl/9Q1sPEdm957z5FhL9